# The ending "to" in sentences

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences is correct? Can we say both of them are correct?

> So that you can get where you want...
> So that you can get where you want to...

Answer (score 1):

Using "to where" is superfluous - just drop "to."

Neither is correct. But either "Get where you want /want to" is a perfect way to say it.

Comment: Yes sry, that was a mistake. My main concern however, is the final to which you answered...